# Can't handle some Import-module errors

Tags: powershell

I was trying to handle errors in powershell step on SQL Job.
any other module reports error as usual but not this one MSAL.PS.

[image: Unable to catch error info]

This results in wrong exit code at the end, step fails. I'm not an expert but until now I've been handling errors succesfully on my scripts. In this case, i can't figure out why is this error different than the others, It don't get registered so I'm not sure how to handle it.

Thanks in advance

Unfortunately, changing global:erroractionpreference gets the same results. The transcript records the error, I've tried to ignore the error action for this module, same results too. I can't find a way to skip it.

```
Transcript started, output file is
#1 Loading PsModules...
# RSAT
# RSAT Found
# SQLserver
# SQLServer module Ready
# Microsoft.Graph.Authentication
# MsGraph modules Ready
# Microsoft.Graph.Users
# MsGraph modules Ready
# MSAL.PS
**********************
Command start time: 20230614100905
**********************
**PS>TerminatingError(Add-Type): "Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information."**
# MSAL module Ready
```

Comment: Try to set `$global:ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` before importing that module.

Comment: Unfortunately, same results. The transcript records the error, I've tried to ignore the error action for this module, I can't find a way to skip it.

Comment: Looking at the [source of the error](https://github.com/AzureAD/MSAL.PS/blob/214619432df4a4d2f902ac2a05b1893403f212a9/src/MSAL.PS.ps1#L88), they are already catching the error. This still causes the `$Error` variable to be populated though. The error is [rethrown](https://github.com/AzureAD/MSAL.PS/blob/214619432df4a4d2f902ac2a05b1893403f212a9/src/MSAL.PS.ps1#LL53C32-L53C50) only if configuration setting `dll.lenientLoading` is `$false`.

Comment: Even passing the argument dll.lenientLoading value as $false, the error still throws. The module works for me, but the job still thinks that something went wrong.

Comment: So, your problem is that the `$Error` variable gets populated, despite `try/catch`? Unfortunately that can't be avoided, script-terminating errors are always recorded. As a workaround you could save/restore the `$Error` variable.

Comment: Had to separate the script execution from the SQL job step. I rather like not to do that but seems the only way for now. tyvm anyway